# Как вытащить строчку из списка python?

Tags: python

есть такая проблемка, у меня есть следущий код:
`button = ['тут какой то текст \n поделеный на строчки \n вот таким образом']`
Задача состоит в том, что мне нужно вытащить каждую строчку и поместить их в разные переменные, например:
`stro1 = "тут такой то текст"`
`stro2 = "поделеный на строчки"`
подскажите, возможно глупый вопрос, но все же?)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: посмотрите str.split()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
button = ['some text \n another text \n that way']

splited_button = button[0].split("\n")

stro1 = splited_button[0]
stro2 = splited_button[1]
stro3 = splited_button[2]
```